# Count specific values and aggregating result in dataframe using transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transform

I have a dataframe similar to this :

```
    Errorid  Matricule Priority
0      1        01       P1
1      2        01       P2
2      3        01       NC
3      4        02       P1
4      5        02       P4
5      6        02       EDC
6      7        02       P2
```

This list all the errors for a Matricule and their priority.

What I want to do is count all the errors for a Matricule **while excluding "NC" and "EDC"** and put the result in the **same** dataframe.

Result example :

```
    Errorid  Matricule Priority  NberrorsMatricule
0      1        01       P1           2
1      2        01       P2           2
2      3        01       NC           2
3      4        02       P1           3
4      5        02       P4           3
5      6        02       EDC          3
6      7        02       P2           3
```

I tried multiple things like below:

```
DF['NberrorsMatricule'] = DF.groupby('Matricule')['Pirority'].transform(lambda x : x.count() if x in ['P1','P2','P3','P4']) 

DF['NberrorsMatricule'] = DF.groupby('Matricule')[DF['Pirority'] in ['P1','P2','P3','P4']].transform("count")
```

Each time I get an ambiguous value error.
    ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), a.all().

Note that this one work :

```
DF['NberrorsMatricule'] = DF.groupby('Matricule')['Pirority'].transform("count")
```

But it obviously don't filter the pirority.

These dataframe are example, in reality I work with a huge amount of data ( more than 400k occurrence in this one) 
So
If someone can help me understand the behavior of transform(), and how to efficiently filter the data It would be very nice.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace non matched values to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), so if use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) it exclude missing values:

```
L = ['P1','P2','P3','P4']
df['NberrorsMatricule'] = (df['Priority'].where(df['Priority'].isin(L))
                                         .groupby(df['Matricule'])
                                         .transform('count'))
print (df)
   Errorid  Matricule Priority  NberrorsMatricule
0        1          1       P1                  2
1        2          1       P2                  2
2        3          1       NC                  2
3        4          2       P1                  3
4        5          2       P4                  3
5        6          2      EDC                  3
6        7          2       P2                  3
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Priority'].where(df['Priority'].isin(L)))
0     P1
1     P2
2    NaN
3     P1
4     P4
5    NaN
6     P2
Name: Priority, dtype: object
```

Another solution is count matched values by `sum`, for convert `True` and `False` to `1, 0` is possible use [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['NberrorsMatricule'] = (df['Priority'].isin(L)
                                         .view('i1')
                                         .groupby(df['Matricule'])
                                         .transform('sum'))
print (df)

   Errorid  Matricule Priority  NberrorsMatricule
0        1          1       P1                  2
1        2          1       P2                  2
2        3          1       NC                  2
3        4          2       P1                  3
4        5          2       P4                  3
5        6          2      EDC                  3
6        7          2       P2                  3
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well ! I like the "SQL like" logic. What is, in your second exemple, the ".view('i1') ?

Comment: Nevermind for the view(), I read the link you put in the answer :D

Comment: @zonas - Sorry, i dont see second part of comment, It convert boolean to `1,0`. You can omi tit, but then get `2.0` and `3.0` instead integers `2,3`

Comment: While applying your method, I was confronted to a problem : I had values added on my resulst when I added another condition to the Df.where(). After looked doc about its behavior I finally understand : the "where" here don't behave like an SQL "where". It replace values that are not valided by conditions but it keep occurrences that have these wrong values.  You probably know this already, that's why you showed me the "details". I Just put this here in case someone, like me, get the wrong idea about the df.where().

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [567]:  df['NberrorsMatricule'] = df[~df.Priority.isin(['NC', 'EDC'])].\ 
     ...:                               groupby('Matricule')['Errorid']\ 
     ...:                               .transform('count')
```

**To remove `Nan`, use `ffill()`:**

```
In [595]: df['NberrorsMatricule'] = df['NberrorsMatricule'].ffill()                                                                                                                                         

In [596]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[596]: 
   Errorid  Matricule Priority  NberrorsMatricule
0        1          1       P1                2.0
1        2          1       P2                2.0
2        3          1       NC                2.0
3        4          2       P1                3.0
4        5          2       P4                3.0
5        6          2      EDC                3.0
6        7          2       P2                3.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution put NaN on the results, which I don't want. But thanks for the answer. It helped me understand things